# "The fact of it being ..." vs "the fact of its being ..."

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, nonfinite-verbs, possessive-vs-oblique

Which one of the following is correct/preferred?

> This process is devised in such a way that it works automatically
>   while always revealing to the user the fact of **it/its** being
>   intact.

Both "the fact of it being ..." and "the fact of its being ..." can be frequently found on the web. But perhaps one should be correct/preferred.

Comment: I use both but am unsure.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how these words are being used.

If you say "Its being..." then *being* is a **gerund** and *its* is the possessive case. *its* and the words that follow it form a noun:

> I was happy about *its being a well established rule*.

It sounds a little strange with *its*, but if I gave another example using another possessive pronoun, *his* then:

> I was happy about *his being accepted*.

If you say "It being", then *being* is then a **participle** describing *it*:

> I was happy about it *being a well established rule.*

And with another example:

> I was happy about him *being accepted*.

There is a subtle difference difference in focus when using one or the other. I can best show what I mean with this example:

> We were amazed by *his singing.*
>
> We were amazed by him *singing*.

Comment: Consider: "I wasn't happy about him calling me".

Comment: @tchrist. I don't see anything significantly different about that example  "I wasn't happy about him, calling me", is like saying "I wasn't happy about that dirty dog, making footprints on my clean kitchen floor."

Comment: The difference is that *calling* is the head of the non-finite verb phrase that is the object of the preposition and *him* is that verb phrase's objective-case subject (only finite verbs have nominative subjects). See Professor Lawler’s  answers: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/156882 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94272 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/275149