# Usage of We and Us, which is correct in this context?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Which sentence is correct and why?

- The good thing is us being together again in all situations.
- The good thing is that we are together again in all situations.

Also, if #1 is the correct one, would it be correct to leave out 'us' so that the sentence is "The good thing is being together again in all situations."

Comment: (1) is more colloquial, I would say. You could also use  'our being together'.

Comment: It depends on the nuance intended.

Comment: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156875/using-objective-pronouns-as-the-subject-of-a-verb-when-is-it-okay) (using the ACC-ing structure as subject) ('Him getting drunk was annoying') is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are correct.

In the first sentence the subject is "the good thing" and the predicate is "is." "Us" is a personal pronoun in the objective case, and that's what it should be because after the predicate there should be an object. "Being together again in all situations" qualifies the object in a correct way.

The second sentence has a different structure but it's just as grammatical. The difference is that the second sentence is complex - there are 2 clauses with the conjunction "that" between them. The first sentence is one-clause.

"The good thing is being together again in all situations" is also correct. Now your object is a gerund.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Have a good day :)